# How to serialize hashmap in android

Tags: android, json, serialization

I want to serialize and deserialize very big hashmaps in android.
I'm using this code:

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
objectOutputStream.writeObject(map);
objectOutputStream.close();
fileOutputStream.close();
```

But the output file I get is very big (300MB). How can I reduce the size?
I tried serializing a json string instead, that minimized it to about 150MB which is still way too big .

Comment: How big are your hashmaps? What types of data do they hold? If you have a very large amount of data then there will be a limit to how small you can compress it.

Comment: how about using `GZIPOutputStream` w/ json?

Comment: The hashmaps are of type Map<String, HashMap<String, double[]>>.

Comment: if persisting the data is very important you may want to look at another way to accomplish this goal. 300mb seems huge, even a 150mb json string is huge. I wonder what the size of this data structure is in ram and how it is a affecting your overall app performance...